# MongoDB AddToSet from Javascript function

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection (Registers) with documents with the following format:

```
{ id_: 1, parentId: 1000, columnValues: [ 'T1, 'T2', 'T3, 'T4', 'T5' ], tags: [ ] }
```

when I try to run this script:

```
db.eval(function() 
{ 
   db.Registers.find({ 'parentId' : '1000', 'columnValues.3' : 'T1' })
               .forEach(function(r) 
                   { 
                       r.tags.add('TAG1'); 
                       db.Registers.save(r); 
                   }); 
})
```

I get the error:

> Object  has no method 'add'

so, the standard 'add' method is not working for adding elements to an array. (tags is an array).

How should it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: When I Perform r.tags = [ 'TAG1'] instead of r.tags.add('TAG1') it works perfect. But I require to add the value to the existing array.

Comment: Why are you doing this `eval`? It's not necessary and you shouldn't use `eval` in general.

Comment: Suppose I want to apply a expression to all the documents in a collection to create a new field on it

Comment: Don't use eval for that. Use a [parallel collection scan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/parallelCollectionScan/) and update each document.

Answer (score 0):

You need `$push` (or `$addToSet` to maintain unique values).

Comment: I know how to use those modifyers when using the update syntax, but on JavaScript I have no clue!